# AMS1117 3.3 V overheating with ESP-01 and 5 V input power

Tags: esp8266, thermal

In our "smart home" I want to integrate the gas consumption into the home server. The gas meter emits a magnetic pulse for every 0.001㎥ gas consumed.

I have designed the following circuit to transmit this pulse to the home assistant, and when powered with a 3.7 V battery it works really well. However, when connecting it to a 5 V USB power supply, the [AMS1117](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) is overheating within a few seconds.

[image: gas counter]

The AMS1117 is rated at a maximum temperature of 125°C. Taking the 5 V input voltage and a peak consumption of 0.2 A, the ASM1117 has to dissipate

`Pd = (5 - 3.3) × 0.2 = 340 mW`

Given an ambient temperature of 25°C, the junction temperature should not exceed 50°C:

`25°C + Pd × 70°C = 25°C + 0,34 × 70 = 48.8°C` (see [here](https://envistiamall.com/blogs/envistia-mall-blog/ams1117-3-3v-and-5v-module-output-current-vs-voltage-soa-curves))

Am I doing something wrong here? Any ideas on how I could improve the design?

Comment: Don't RST and EN need to be connected (to an RC pair and to Vcc respectively)? // Have you measured the actual current consumption with an ammeter or shunt resistor?

Comment: Pd is in Watts not mA. (V * I). And are you sure you have a good regulator? Cheap knockoff?

Comment: @Passerby Thanks for the correction. I guess, V in this case is the drop-off voltage (1.7V)? The component I got from Amazon, so it's very possible, that this is a cheap knockoff!

Comment: @TypeIA The current consumption I got from the data sheet of the ESP-01 (80mA in average and 170mA peek). Now I also measured the power consumption, and it's actually 70mA. I think **Passerby** might be correct with the assumption of a cheap component. I'll check where I can find a proper one, and give it another try.

Comment: A cheap component would have poorere Rth die-case, which wouldn't change the dissippation (unles it dissipates itself directly to ground, which would be very weird), and if anything it would lower the case temperature (but raise the chip temperature). What exactly do you mean by overheating? Too hot to touch? Or does it thermally shutdown?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen it thermally shuts down. I exchanged the component with another one from the same batch, and it seems to be running at a lower temperature now. It's still getting surprisingly warm, and I'll monitor it now for a few hours. Thanks for all the help so far!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for your support, with your help I figured out what actually happened. I have multiple ESP-01 modules, and one of them is broken in some way. As soon as I plug this one in to the board I have designed (see question), it's overheating and breaking the AMS1117 within seconds. From that point on, the AMS1117 is overheating even when plugging in another module.

After replacing the AMS1117 once again and trowing away the defect ESP-01 module, everything seems to be working fine.